# Is it Possible use maxretry 0 in my jail.conf?

Tags: linux, centos, fail2ban

Well my question is I can use `maxretry = 0` in my jail.conf?

here is my [DEFAULT]

**EDIT** *I removed the old code now i added all the jail.conf file.*
some parts of code are removed in here not in my jail.conf

```sh
[DEFAULT]
bantime = 1h
banaction = iptables-multiport
[sshd]
enabled = true
[DEFAULT]
ignoreip = 127.0.0.1/8
ignorecommand =
bantime  = 1h
findtime  = 6h
maxretry = 1
maxmatches = %(maxretry)s
backend = auto
usedns = warn
logencoding = auto
enabled = false
mode = normal
filter = %(__name__)s[mode=%(mode)s]
destemail = root@localhost
sender = Fail2Ban
mta = sendmail
protocol = tcp
chain = <known/chain>
port = 0:65535
fail2ban_agent = Fail2Ban/%(fail2ban_version)s
banaction = iptables-multiport
banaction_allports = iptables-allports
action_ = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
action_mw = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
            %(mta)s-whois[name=%(__name__)s, sender="%(sender)s", dest="%(destemail)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
action_mwl = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
             %(mta)s-whois-lines[name=%(__name__)s, sender="%(sender)s", dest="%(destemail)s", logpath="%(logpath)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
action_xarf = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
             xarf-login-attack[service=%(__name__)s, sender="%(sender)s", logpath="%(logpath)s", port="%(port)s"]
action_cf_mwl = cloudflare[cfuser="%(cfemail)s", cftoken="%(cfapikey)s"]
                %(mta)s-whois-lines[name=%(__name__)s, sender="%(sender)s", dest="%(destemail)s", logpath="%(logpath)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
action_blocklist_de  = blocklist_de[email="%(sender)s", service=%(filter)s, apikey="%(blocklist_de_apikey)s", agent="%(fail2ban_agent)s"]
action_badips = badips.py[category="%(__name__)s", banaction="%(banaction)s", agent="%(fail2ban_agent)s"]
action_badips_report = badips[category="%(__name__)s", agent="%(fail2ban_agent)s"]
action_abuseipdb = abuseipdb
action = %(action_)s
[sshd]
port    = ssh
logpath = %(sshd_log)s
backend = pyinotify
```

Answer (score 3):

Fail2Ban's [documentation](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/MANUAL_0_8) states:

| Name | Default | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| filter |  | Name of the filter to be used by the jail to detect matches. Each single match by a filter increments the counter within the jail |
| logpath | /var/log/messages | Path to the log file which is provided to the filter |
| **maxretry** | 3 | **Number of matches (i.e. value of the counter) which triggers ban action on the IP.** |
| findtime | 600 sec | The counter is set to zero if no match is found within "findtime" seconds. |
| bantime | 600 sec | Duration (in seconds) for IP to be banned for. Negative number for "permanent" ban. |

Use a value of `1` to ban the IP after the **first** failed attempt.

```
maxretry = 1
```

Comment: thank you so much but i still get alot of failed logins like 10 minutes i get 150 failed logins i cant make it 0? or any other way

Comment: I guess thats an other issue. Are you sure you're applying it to the right jail?

Comment: I will edit my question with my jail.conf